# Image in table td taking up all the width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have got a table with an image in one of the columns. The problem is that the td containing the image is taking up all the remaining space left after taking up necessary space for other tds.
My question is whether this behavior is normal? If not, how can I fix this?

Please see my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/abhi2000/pen/jDaEn).

FYi the images are from http://randomuser.me/ and I am using knockout for data-binding.

Thanks,
Abhi.

Comment: Why not just limit the size of the image with CSS?

Comment: Hi PW Kad, I have set the max-width and min-width for the img as an inline style.

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Hi Kate,I was expecting the table to divide the width equally among all the td elements.

Comment: Can you just have a width of 25% for every column? That should equalize them. Tables tend to have a mind of their own if you don't tell them how to look.

Comment: Yes, it would. But ideally I would like the columns to take the width based on the content as the actual content may vary in length. Secondly, I am perplexed by this behavior and am trying to understand why it's behaving like this.

Comment: You might have to at least set a width on the cell containing your images, if you know that the images will always be the same width. The other cells will resize dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I have changed my pen giving a width to the td containing the image. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems maybe having a max percentage and min px css are causing rendering conflicts. If you remove the min and max width and simply say width 50px you should get the desired result per my understanding.